# Can't get State from NetWorkInfo Android

Tags: java, android, state, telephonymanager, android-broadcastreceiver

As the title says, I can't get State in Broadcastreceiver from NetWorkInfo Class.

It returns some errors in log output which are given below.

I need your help.

Here is the log output and the Broacastreceiver class , I also notice that I've added all permission (Access Network State et Internet ) and the Broadcast intent  `action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`.

So I dare say there isn't problem in manifest.xml file .

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    State state = activeNetwork.getState();

  switch (state) {

  case CONNECTING:
      Toast.makeText(context, "connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
```

and the log output is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.test.ConnectivityChangeReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2668)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at com.example.test.ConnectivityChangeReceiver.onReceive(ConnectivityChangeReceiver.java:27)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2653)
```

Comment: What is line 27 `ConnectivityChangeReceiver.java`?

Comment: this is my broadcastreceiver class

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NPE on this line `activeNetwork.getState()` and it is because `activeNetwork` is `null`. **This may return null when there is no default network.**

Make sure there is Active Network when you are testing this app. In that case `activeNetwork.getState()` should be non-null.

If your objective is to test network connectivity for Wi-Fi and mobile, then you may try using below code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
        boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
        networkInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();


        Log.d("ConnectivityChangeReceiver", "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
        Log.d("ConnectivityChangeReceiver", "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```

This code  determines whether these network interfaces are available (that is, whether network connectivity is possible) and/or connected (that is, whether network connectivity exists and if it is possible to establish sockets and pass data.

Also, you should not base decisions on whether a network is "available." You should always check isConnected() before performing network operations, since isConnected() handles cases like flaky mobile networks, airplane mode, and restricted background data.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the following permissions in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```